# How do you replace a nested array with a flattened version of itself in jq?

Tags: json, bash, jq

Taking a json file as input such as:

```json
{"computers":
    [{"host":"example",
    "platform":"some_platform",
    "status":
        {"working":"yes",
        "display":["no"]},
    "description":""
    }]
}
```

...how can this be flattened to this form:

```json
{"computers":
    "host":"example",
    "platform":"some_platform",
    "working":"yes",
    "display":"no",
    "description":""
}
```

ie. the status element has been flattened, the square brackets in `"display":["no"]` have been removed, and the square brackets around `"computers":[...]` have been removed.

I have so far tried using flatten in multiple ways, eg.:

```
cat ./output.json | jq '.computers|.[]|.status|flatten'
```

but this only outputs the flattened version of the contents of the status element. I cannot work out how to replace the contents with the flattened version.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure the `computers` array will just contain a single object, you could use:

```
.computers |= (first | . + .status | del(.status) | (.display |= join(.)))
```

That will alter the value of `.computers` by doing to following:

- Get the `first` object
- Move everything inside `.status` to the object itself
- `del()` the `.status` key
- `join()` on the `.display` to get single value instead of the array.

Output:

```json
{
  "computers": {
    "host": "example",
    "platform": "some_platform",
    "description": "",
    "working": "yes",
    "display": "no"
  }
}
```

##### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/QoRwdYFuNMt)

---

If there could be multiple objects in the `computer` array, `first` will ensure the first object is used.

We could also use `last` to get the last one:

```
.computers |= (last | . + .status | del(.status) | (.display |= join(.)))
```

Or combine `map()` and `add` to loop over all the objects, and add them together, then the the keys will be overwritten so the last value will stay visible, this might be handy if not all the objects have all the keys:

```
.computers |= (map(. + .status | del(.status) | (.display |= join(.))) | add)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your JSON structure is fixed, the following could do:

```
.computers
| first
| { host, platform, description }
+ (.status | .display |= first)
| { computers: . }
```

or

```
.computers
| first
| del(.status) + (.status | .display |= first)
| { computers: . }
```

or

```
{
    computers: (
        .computers[0] | del(.status) + (.status | .display |= first)
    )
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "computers": {
    "host": "example",
    "platform": "some_platform",
    "description": "",
    "working": "yes",
    "display": "no"
  }
}
```

Another alternative is reassigning the computers property, similar to 0stone0's solution, but a little bit shorter:

```
.computers |= (first | del(.status) + (.status | .display |= first))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generically "flatten" nested objects by recursively traversing to their `scalars`, and putting them together by taking the deepest field name available:

```bash
.computers |= ([paths(scalars) as $p | {($p | map(strings)[-1]): getpath($p)}] | add)
```

```json
{
  "computers": {
    "host": "example",
    "platform": "some_platform",
    "working": "yes",
    "display": "no",
    "description": ""
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/iPFQkJyptVw)

Note: You didn't define how arrays should be handled in the general case. For instance, what should happen if the `.computers` array or the `.display` array had more than just that single element. This approach merges them with latter elements overwriting previous ones if field names in the result object clash.